# Ошибка "Недопустимое неявное преобразование типа данных datetime в тип данных int" в SQL-запросе

Tags: sql, sql-server

Задание :"Показать имена и фамилии так же и колличество их заказов, отправленных после заданной даты на протяжении 1997 года (используя left join)" (англ версия:"Show first and last names of the employees as well as the count of their orders shipped after required date during the year 1997 (use left join)")

На данный момент я имею такой запрос:

```
SELECT 
  FirstName, 
  LastName, 
  COUNT(OrderID) as Count_of_Orders
FROM Orders 
LEFT JOIN Employees 
  ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
WHERE ShippedDate BETWEEN RAND(ShippedDate) 
  AND '1997-12-31' 
  AND DATEPART(YY,ShippedDate) = 1997
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

Но выдаёт ошибку :"Недопустимое неявное преобразование типа данных datetime в тип данных int, таблица "Orders", столбец "ShippedDate". Для выполнения этого запроса используйте функцию CONVERT."
Уже всё перепробовала, но не могу правильно конвертировать данные

Comment: RAND это же получение случайного числа, чего вы пытаетесь добиться получая случайное число от ShppedDate ? было бы логично если бы в between были бы просто две явно заданные даты ОТ и ДО и тогда бы условие `DATEPART(YY,ShippedDate) = 1997` было бы не нужно, поточу что between бы выбрал как раз только нужный диапазон дат

Comment: в условии сказано что нужно от установленной даты и до конца года. Вот и хотелось чтобы выбирало из списка имеющихся дат. 
Когда пишешь условие 
WHERE ShippedDate BETWEEN '1997-02-01' AND '1997-12-31'  
Выдает ошибку "Преобразование типа данных varchar в тип данных datetime привело к выходу значения за пределы диапазона."

Comment: Значит у вас в БД принят другой формат даты, например год-день-месяц или еще как. узнайте как правильно задавать даты в вашей БД. И никакого смысла выбирать даты из существующих нет. Ну и rand если почитаете его описание, увидите что он возвращает просто случайное число (тип int), случайную дату он вернуть физически не может.

Answer (score 0):

- Данная ошибка возникает при выполнении RAND(), так как аргументом функции может быть только целочисленное выражение (tinyint, smallint или int).
- Ваш запрос будет работать вот так:

  ```
  declare @startdate datetime = '19970101' --заданная дата

  SELECT FirstName, LastName, COUNT(OrderID) as Count_of_Orders
  FROM Orders 
  LEFT JOIN Employees ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
  WHERE DATEPART(YY,ShippedDate) = 1997 AND ShippedDate >= @startdate
  Group by FirstName, LastName
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю свое решение.
В условии указано `"orders shipped after required date"`, то есть доставленные позже необходимой даты!

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, COUNT(OrderID) as Count_of_Orders
FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Employees 
ON Orders.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID
WHERE DATEPART(YY,ShippedDate)=1997 AND ShippedDate > RequiredDate 
Group by FirstName, LastName
```